# Excluding previously visited URL from new search

Tags: google-search, search-engines

I am trying to find something on craigslist via google chrome. The search string looks like this
"ItemDescription site:craigslist.org" However every time I search this results in quite a decent result set. As I comb through the results, I have found that a lot of posts have been "deleted by author" which is understandable. The next time I search, since I cannot get through the subset in a single setting, the already visited posts still show up on top, requiring me to pass through several next pages before landing on an unvisited result.

I am curious to know if there is any modifier that I can use to exclude previously visited URLs. If not is there any to have them displayed towards the end of the result set?

If there is an alternative search engine that is fine too...

Answer (score 1):

You can use exclusions in the google search string by using the minus operator.

The search would look like:

```
ItemDescription -"deleted by author" site:craigslist.org
```

See
[Google Search Operators: The Complete List (42 Advanced Operators)](https://ahrefs.com/blog/google-advanced-search-operators/).

Comment: Good thought, but didn't return what the expected would have been. Deleted posts still show in the results

Comment: You can add as many exclusion strings as you need. The problem might be if Google indexing isn't up to date.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Search results are rendered on a Google server somewhere in their datacenter. Visited pages are stored in your browser's history on your computer. Locally stored history is not shared with servers to protect your privacy. Therefore the server can't filter out pages you've already visited.

Comment: That makes sense. I wonder if there is any utility or extension that can work as intermediate and exclude or show only the previous visited site. Alternatively now I am wondering if there is a way to search by published date.